# All-wheel drive single tire placement

Tags: tires, subaru, replace, awd

We have an all-wheel drive Subaru. A few months ago we had one tire blow on a set that was around a year old. We were told (by the tire store) we had to replace all of them. That sounded nuts but I researched it a little and it appears to be true. $870 for 4 high-performance tires.

Now, around 4 months later, we have blown another tire. The (same) tire store is telling us it's okay to replace just one tire because of the age of the tires. They are under warranty.

This sounds reasonable, but I just want to make sure this isn't a case of the tire company getting out of replacing all of the tires. Are there any guidelines for tread wear where it's not safe to replace a single tire on an all-wheel drive vehicle? In this case we were told there was 11/32 tread depth which I guess is like new.

Thanks.

Comment: I can tell you there is truth to the "different sized tire" issue and you can ruin a lot more than $900 in parts trying to get away with it.  Each manufacturer will have their own tolerances.  I'd check with a dealer before trusting the tire shop, but it is in their best interest to be correct to avoid lawsuits.  There are some Subaru guys on here that might _know_ more.

Comment: I read the Subaru has one of the smallest tolerances.

Comment: If you look at the question marked as a duplicate, you'll see a situation that is very similar to your own.  Summary: you want matching tires but it's your car and your responsibility to make an informed decision.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to make an informed decision that's why I posted this question. Thanks.